# What is the definition of this tag in Maven: <exclude.bootstrap>

Tags: maven

I have the following property in Maven and I cannot find any information about it:

```
<properties>
    <!-- development mode (exclude in production) -->
    <exclude.bootstrap>true</exclude.bootstrap>
</propertes/>
```

Thanks for pointing me to the right documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen something like this before. IMHO this is just a regular, your own (or POM's author) property, probably used somewhere in this POM or its modules. There is an option that this is a special property, maybe related to some of declared plugins, but - as I said - I haven't used a plugin that uses this.